# Unresolved Error

Tags: c++, linker-errors, visual-c++-6, unresolved-external

While I am compiling its giving error message :

```
usimage.cpp
Generating Code...
Linking...
   Creating library .\Output/gci2.lib and object .\Output/gci2.exp
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffclos
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffgpxv
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffthdu
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffgisz
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffgidm
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffghdt
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffdkopn
guide_routines.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "float __cdecl CalcSlope(class DoubleArray)" (?CalcSlope@@YAMVDoubleArray@@@Z)
.\Release/gci2.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
PixCel.exe - 9 error(s), 3 warning(s)
```

I changed project setting to multithreaded and liked Vfw32.lib but no change...

I am using vc++ 6.0 and xp plateform...

Comment: It's not when you are *compiling", it's when you are *linking*.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a library when linking, try adding the fitsio library (I believe that's what you are trying to use) to your link path.

Comment: Yeah I want to link with fitsio library , and I am linking it with the program but why its not getting linked that i cant understand , what can be the solution , can you please suggest me ???

Comment: Here what happening , its completing checking all the file , so i think it doesnt find an error during compilation . Then when it is linking with library

"Linking...
   Creating library .\Output/gci2.lib and object .\Output/gci2.exp
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffclos
cam_simulator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ffgpxv
"

its generating the error , i have linked properly in my project linker property ..Is it require any other setting or linking ?